# Keras Reproducibility Problem on Jupyter notebook

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, keras, tensorflow, data-science-model

I developed a model with Keras. However, every time I run the model from the beginning, I get different score values. I typed the code below to provide "reproducibility" but unfortunately, I'm still getting different results. Is there any other method you have tried to achieve "Reproducibility"?

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import numpy as np

seed = 0
random.seed(seed)
np.random.seed(seed)


import os    
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = str(seed)
os.environ['TF_DETERMINISTIC_OPS'] = '1'
    

import tensorflow as tf
tf.random.set_random_seed(seed)
tf.set_random_seed(seed)
```

Comment: Thi might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21494489/what-does-numpy-random-seed0-do

Comment: Thank you @rapaio I already solved the problem. Here is the link that I used:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32419510/how-to-get-reproducible-results-in-keras/52897216#52897216